# How to change user agent urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-agent

I'm trying to access a page using the following

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

li_post_id = "post-" + str(post_id)
li_soup = soup.find('li', attrs={'id':li_post_id})
```

This works fine on my ubuntu machine, but when running it on my Windows server I get 403 Forbidden error, so I assume the issue is with the user agent.

How do I change this, say, to Firefox? I have only seen tutorials to change the user agent using requests, but I don't want to change all of my code to this.

Comment: You set `User-Agent` in the HTTP request header, BS has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As stated, BeautifulSoup does not interact at all with the HTTP requests. What (I believe) you really want to know is how to do this with *urllib2*. I edited your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
import random
import requests, bs4


agents= [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)']

headers = {"User-Agent":random.choice(agents)}
response = requests.get(full_url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: The asker has expressed that they have seen answers using `requests`, but they are looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the header doesn't have anything to do with `BeautifulSoup`. It is meant for HTML parsing only. You need to change it in your urllib request like so:

Python3

```
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.build_opener()
req.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Some user agent')]
response = req.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Python2.7

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.build_opener()
req.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Some user agent')]
response = req.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```